# Composer doesn't list forked versions of package

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I'm trying to use the PHP BlockIO package -- https://github.com/BlockIo/block_io-php

It requires a forked version of the bitwasp/bitcoin library. When attempting to update it with composer, or install it, I get an error with a list of versions that generally aren't available in the fork:

```
Root composer.json requires bitwasp/bitcoin dev-minimal, found bitwasp/bitcoin[dev-master, 0.0.1, ..., 0.0.35.x-dev, v1.0.0, ..., 1.0.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint
```

I've checked to make sure that the fork has a branch named minimal, and that the name in the composer.json file on that branch matches, and now I'm lost. I only have the forked branch in this composer.json file, in order to isolate and test:

```
{
    "name": "shorton/temp",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "short one",
            "email": "root@host.local"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/doersf/bitcoin-php.git"
        }
    ],
    "require":{
        "bitwasp/bitcoin": "dev-minimal"
    }
}
```

Any clues on how to get this working?

We have a project that uses this library right now, and 'composer install works', but everything is locked at the exact current version because composer update will not work.

Comment: I don't know why one might expect php composer to know about GitHub forks. Presumably you have to tell it. There are some GitHub APIs to discover stuff, perhaps you could augment composer to use those?

Comment: What's your PHP version? The repo states the forked version is only required for PHP `<8.0`.

Comment: My PHP version is 7.4